# oxyplot axis locking center when mouse wheel

Tags: c#, axis, mousewheel, oxyplot

I'm new to wpf and oxyPlot.
Now, I want create a dynamic line chart like an oscilloscope, but I don't know how to lock the axis on a value when mouse wheel zooms.

**Example:**

[image]

The red point is mouse location. In normal, zoom A -> B, zoom C -> D. now, I want to zoom C ->E, like mouse location at 0 center.

Comment: Do you know that if you zoom with the pointer over one single axe, only that axe will zoom?

Comment: @Kirenenko I know, but not my mean that. If I pointer over one single axis, maybe I want it zoom on center value.

Comment: then what you want to do, block the vertical axis? Maybe a picture/gif showing what you want to achieve will help.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bk3ga7r8xf3xtk8/sample.png?dl=0
red point is mouse location. In normal, zoom A -> B, zoom C -> D.
now, I want to zoom C ->E, likes mouse location at 0 center.

Comment: @Kirenenko Thx.

Comment: Check my answer. Also add the c# tag to your question to see the code formated with colors.

Comment: OK, Thx. I,m new to stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution that works for blocking an axis zoom center. You have to create a custom `LinearAxis` to achieve this:

```
public class FixedCenterLinearAxis : LinearAxis
{
    double center = 0;
    public FixedCenterLinearAxis() : base(){}

    public FixedCenterLinearAxis(double _center) : base()
    {
        center = _center;
    }

    public override void ZoomAt(double factor, double x)
    {
        base.ZoomAt(factor, center);
    }
}
```

You have to use it like that:

```
var bottomAxis = new FixedCenterLinearAxis(0.5) //specify the center value here
{
    Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
};

plotModel.Axes.Add(bottomAxis);
```

If you dont specify a value on the constructor, center value will be 0.

Comment: Thx. It's work. But I have two question.
1. What different from use `ZoomAt()` and `ZoomAtCenter()` directly?
2. If Center value not 0, when I zoom, the center value almost disappear.

Comment: At first I tried using `ZoomAtCenter` inside the overwriten function. But it calls `ZoomAt`, so it causes an infinite loop. Also feel free to accept the answer as the correct one.